# How can I temporarily stop a bathroom water leak?

Tags: plumbing

I'm in the process of remodeling my bathroom and currently have all the cement backerboard torn down. I had to remove the sink in order to get a good portion of the tile off. Unfortunately, my old house has no way of shutting off water to the bathroom so I had to completely shut off water to the house.

I added water shutoff valves to the 1/2" pipes for the sink to stop the water. The valve on the hot water pipe has sealed fine with no leaks. The valve on the cold water pipe continues to leak no matter what I do.
[Where it's leaking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlNql.jpg)

I've installed it using teflon pipe joint compound. For a few hours it's fine with no drips. However, I woke up this morning and it was steadily dripping all over the place. I'm not sure what to do to keep this from making a mess.

It only needs to be temporary as, in the next couple weeks I'm going to replace most of the plumbing in the bathroom—I just need to be able to have water on in my house without also making an indoor swimming pool!

Comment: Which side of the shutoff valve is it leaking from?  Entrance or exit? Or both?

Comment: @treeNinja Just the entrance.

Comment: So either the compression sleeve did not fully get compressed and/or the compression nut is not completely tight.  I have no experience with the Teflon compound (I use the tape) but maybe add a bit more.  Then tighten the compression nut slowly, a 1/4 of a turn at a time so you do not over tighten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HomeDepot carries a brand called "SharkBite" that are simple, push-to-connect fittings. You can buy a cap from them for cheap. It requires an equally inexpensive plastic tool to remove. That, or something like it, should get the job done.

The cap: http://www.homedepot.com/p/SharkBite-1-2-in-Brass-Push-Fit-End-Stop-U514LFA/202270531

The removal tool: http://www.homedepot.com/p/SharkBite-1-2-in-Disconnect-Clip-U710A/100638139

Comment: Oh, great! That sounds just like what I need. Can they be pushed onto a threaded pipe, or will it need to be unthreaded?

Answer (score 1):

Sharkbite fittings require a clean cut pipe end to install. You could try what I did last night with the same issue. I took off the tape dope and applied some white dope compound I had from back in the day. Comes in a small white tube at the big box stores. No leaks afterwards!